# how can I turn strings into numbers in d3js

Tags: d3.js

My data set is csv and I am trying to convert some metrics from strings into numbers, here is the code:

```
**async function drawLineChart() {

  const dataset = await d3.csv ("./../../data.csv");
  const dateParser = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
  const xAccessor = d => dateParser(d.date);
  const yAccessor = d => d.sales ;**
```

How can I convert sales from a string into a number before yAccessor function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily convert string to number either by using Number function or using (+) operator.

```
  const yAccessor = d => Number(d.sales);
```

or

```
  const yAccessor = d => +d.sales;
```